# Creating an Android library for re-distribution like paypal via proguard

Tags: android, encoding

I have been working for one of the project where I am required to do the following.

Current Status: I have developed an Android app for which we are currently distributing apk files to the users. But the problem is, if users want to alter any designs etc, we have to take that pain, instead, we want to make sure the view files are available to them, but the core logic is in the jar file. Now, creating jar file is not an issue, but we still want to secure the source code. So, I found ProGuard http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/introduction.html

Now, the examples there shows that apk file which will be generate will have obfuscated codes. But I just want my classes under the jar files to be obfuscated.

Any help will be appreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit which classes should be left original and which ones should be obfuscated.
For example you may not want to obfuscate Activities or Services or Android will not be able to find them anymore ;-)

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring

You can also use proguard on its own and pre-obfuscate your jar file before using it in the app itself.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! pre-obfuscated jar did a trick for me!! Will post full details in next comment on how I got it worked :)